# F# Memoization - Persist?

Tags: functional-programming, f#, memoization

What's the best way to persist/save the results of memoization so it can be loaded later?

There's this standard code snippet in F# for implementing memoization:

```fs
let memoize f =
    let dict = Dictionary<_, _>();
    fun c ->
        let exist, value = dict.TryGetValue c
        match exist with
        | true -> value
        | _ -> 
            let value = f c
            dict.Add(c, value)
            value

let mySlowFunc x= 
    // something very slow
    0

let myFastFunc = memoize mySlowFunc
```

After calling myFastFunc many times, I will have a dictionary full of results for mySlowFunc for various x's. I want to persist these results so ideally I can do something like:

```fs
let saveMemoziationResults myFastFunc "results.file" = ... // saves the dict to a file
```

```fs
let loadMemoziationResults "results.file" // loads the dict from a file
```

I can't figure out a way to "access" that dict in order to save it.

Comment: The complicated inner state like this should be better managed with class type, say it takes function and file name string (or generalized persisting method) in constructor and defines methods like _.Invoke(arg) for function call with memoization, _.SaveMemo() and _.UpdateMemo() for saving and updating cache in/from file. You can then make it to save the cache for every fixed number of new calls and other tweaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move dict creation to the caller, like

```
let memoizeBase dict =
    let memoize f = …
    memoize
```

And using it like

```
let dict = new…
let memoize = memoizeBase dict
// use memoize and save/load dict when needed
```